# Keycloack throws Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource

Tags: docker, keycloak

I have a key cloak docker instance when i load keycloack login using HTTPS its throws as Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource and ui keeps loading

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason is that you didn't provide hostname configuration.

To do that, either set the `KC_HOSTNAME` environment variable in your Docker container, or add `--hostname` argument to the Keycloak start command.

```
// Dockerfile
ENV KC_HOSTNAME="example.com"

// CLI (alternative)
kc.sh start --hostname "example.com"
```

Also, if you're exposing Admin console in a different hostname, then additionally you need to provide `KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN` env variable or `--hostname-admin` argument.

See [Configuring the hostname](https://www.keycloak.org/server/hostname) documentation page on that.